# move files whose creation time or modified time is less than 25 mins to a different folder in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want move a file from dir1 to dir2 in ubuntu , but the catch is it should move if the creation time or modified time is less than 25 minutes.

please suggest command for this.

I am using ubuntu 18.04lts

Answer (score 0):

Do you try `find` command with `-mmin` option:

```bash
find dir1 -type f -mmin -25 -exec mv {} d2 \;
```

see `man find` for more explanations